# Functions with Bernoulli Number Product Coefficients

Tags: functions, power-series, taylor-expansion, bernoulli-numbers

I am trying to construct a function with 2 Bernoulli Numbers Product.
For example we have a following for cotangent:

$$\cot(z)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k 2^{2 k} B_{2 k} z^{2 k-1}}{(2 k)!}+\frac{1}{z}$$

I would like to construct something like:

$$new(z)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k 2^{2 k} B_{2 k}B_{2k+c} z^{2 k-1}}{(2 k)!}$$

where $c$ is any arbitrary natural number. Any example or partial solution is appreciated.

I have an assumption that this can be constructed from the 2 variable $\cot(x,y)$-function by setting the $x$ and $y$ to z.

Comment: For odd values of $c$, it seems to be $0$. Even for $c=0$, I did not get anything (even in terms of special functions).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes the odd values obviously 0. It seems for $B_{4k}B_{4k+2c}$ there is some result. Will update the post soon.